# Open stream_url of a Soundcloud Track via Client-Side XHR?

Tags: streaming, html5-audio, soundcloud, cors, web-audio-api

Since you can call the the Soundcloud API via XHR
(because of the CORS headers it sends http://backstage.soundcloud.com/2010/08/of-cors-we-do/, right?)
I was wondering if this was possible with the audio data itself, like a tracks' stream_url for example.

When trying to open the stream_url with a XHR (from the Client Side) using the Web Audio API, i get a *Origin  is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.* error.
Is there a way to load Audio resources via XHttpRequest from Client-Side-Javascript, or is it impossible ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871882/audio-data-api-and-streaming-a-no-go) ?

Would be great as this would allow some really cool things with the Web Audio API.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

The problem might have to do with the 302 redirect you get when calling:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/5646378/stream.json?client_id=[client_id]
```

or some other call requesting the actual media file (see comments).

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 24 Jun 2012 09:58:01 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Location: http://ec-media.soundcloud.com/[...]
X-Runtime: 41
Content-Length: 339
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Cacheable: NO:Cache-Control=no-cache
X-Varnish: 2433107209
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
X-Cache: MISS

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=252460800
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Date: Sun, 24 Jun 2012 09:58:01 GMT
ETag: "c2241e[...]41bbcf7c0d32f09"
Last-Modified: Tue, 28 Sep 2010 17:57:26 GMT
Server: ECAcc (fra/D484)
x-amz-id-2: oB0XzQcc/[...]+mAr/a
x-amz-meta-bitrate: 128
x-amz-meta-duration: 152900
x-amz-meta-job: t405jWkfNvx7
x-amz-request-id: D65[...]E1355
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Length: 2445478
```

The original JSON response has the CORS headers, while the location of the redirect don't.

Comment: should work, for example [http://audiojedit.herokuapp.com (http://audiojedit.herokuapp.com)  and if you're running from localhost that might be an issue

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that you are using a route on your domain, when actually loading audiofiles via XHR. 
([user]/[track]/audio, right?)
Are you using some kind of proxy or are you open and restream them from the server side?

I'd love to find a solution how to directly open Soundcloud audiofiles in JS via XHR.

Comment: it's not my work! i've basically got the same question as you. they are pulling onto the server and then to the client but it should be same principle no? i've got as far as opening up an mp3 stream but get this error logged to console **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ec-media.soundcloud.com/aJTfLYiG5JV8.128.mp3?ff61182e3c2ecefa438cd02102d0e385713f0c1faf3b0339595667fa0b0deb17ddd8c556aeccfadc70d4883de09c566e229fee29407d1f2af5a224ceeb59601b12e99f95af&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJBHW5FB4ERKUQUOQ&Expires=1340480326&Signature=sXW2L6oS32IlKV9gYjPgKPl9OuI%3D. Cannot make any requests from null.**

Comment: I had this error, too. 
My guess would be that it came from the stream URL getting rewritten to the actual storage location of the media file. Disappeared when i used the resolved URI hardcoded. (i think this could be resolved in JS somehow). But then i get the CORS error described in the question. Seems to me that the streamed audio file might not send those CORS headers...

Comment: yep, got the cors error as well, maybe jsonp will help [http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#crossdomain](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#crossdomain)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, as long as the Audio Files themselves don't come with the CORS headers (see curl -IL output in the question), the only solution that worked for me is open the audio files and add the headers yourself.

From my understanding, this is what other apps like https://github.com/tsenart/audiojedit do too. (in node.js)
This has the the huge downside of shifting the traffic of the binary files to your server, which would be otherwise served by soundcloud.com.

You can use PHP to open the file, add the headers and restream it with something like:

```
$fp = fopen('http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/[track_id]/stream.json?client_id=[client_id]', 'rb');

header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
fpassthru( $fp );

exit();
```

As I said, this is just a workaround, not a nice solution for a production environment,
but helped me keep going with my Web Audio App.

Soundcloud, any chance of adding CORS headers to the audiofiles? :)

Answer (score 5):

If you're not necessarily tied down to using XHR, you could create new `<audio/>` elements and set their `src` to whatever asset you want, without being tied to Same-Origin Policy.

Newer versions of Chrome will allow you to create AudioNode instances from media elements via `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` -- so you can still use all the cool new Web Audio stuff.

```
var audio, body, context, source;
audio = document.createElement('audio');
body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
audio.setAttribute('src', 'http://kevincennis.com/mix/assets/sounds/1901_gtr1.mp3');
body.appendChild(audio);
context = new webkitAudioContext();
source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
source.connect(context.destination);
source.mediaElement.play();
```

Excuse the hideous code. It's late and I'm tired.