# Load audiodata into AudioBufferSourceNode from <audio/> element via createMediaElementSource?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

Is it possible to have an audiofile loaded from `<audio/>`-element via `createMediaElementSource` and then load the audio data into a **AudioBufferSourceNode**?

*Using the audio-element as a source (MediaElementSource) seems not to be an option, as I want to use Buffer methods like `noteOn` and `noteGrain`.*

*Loading the audiofile directly to the buffer via XHR unfortunately isn't an option neither*
( see [Open stream_url of a Soundcloud Track via Client-Side XHR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165726/open-stream-url-of-a-soundcloud-track-via-client-side-xhr))

Loading the buffer contents from the audio elements seems to be possible though:

http://www.w3.org/2011/audio/wiki/Spec_Differences#Reading_Data_from_a_Media_Element

Or is it even possible to directly use the buffer of an `<audio/>`-element as a sourceNode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today 2020+ it is possible via the audioWorklet Node

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor/AudioWorkletProcessor

Running in the AudioWorkletContext so only that is there you can pass the binary raw data via messages

```js
// test-processor.js
class RecorderWorkletProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
  constructor (options) {
    super()
    console.log(options.numberOfInputs)
    console.log(options.processorOptions.someUsefulVariable)
  }
  // @ts-ignore 
  process(inputs, output, parameters) {
      /**
      * @type {Float32Array} length 128 Float32Array(128)
      * non-interleaved IEEE754 32-bit linear PCM 
      * with a nominal range between -1 and +1, 
      * with each sample between -1.0 and 1.0.
      * the sample rate depends on the audioContext and is variable
      */
      const inputChannel = inputs[0][0];  //inputChannel Float32Array(128)
      const { postMessage } = this.port;
      postMessage(inputChannel)  // float32Array sent as byte[512] 
      return true; // always do this!
  }
}
```

main code

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext()

const audioMediaElement = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(
  /** @type {HTMLAudioElement} */ audio
);

await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('test-processor.js')
const recorder = new AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, 'test-processor', 
  {
     processorOptions: {
     someUsefulVariable: new Map([[1, 'one'], [2, 'two']])
  }
});

/**
 *   
 * Objects of these types are designed to hold small audio snippets, 
 * typically less than 45 s. For longer sounds, objects implementing 
 * the MediaElementAudioSourceNode are more suitable. 
 * The buffer contains data in the following format: 
 * non-interleaved IEEE754 32-bit linear PCM (LPCM)
 * with a nominal range between -1 and +1, that is, a 32-bit floating point buffer, 
 * with each sample between -1.0 and 1.0.  
 * @param {ArrayBufferLike|Float32Array} data 
 */
 const convertFloatToAudioBuffer = (data) => {
    const sampleRate = 8000 | audioContext.sampleRate
    const channels = 1;
    const sampleLength = 128 | data.length; // 1sec = sampleRate * 1
    const audioBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(channels, sampleLength, sampleRate); // Empty Audio
    audioBuffer.copyToChannel(new Float32Array(data), 0); // depending on your processing this could be already a float32array
    return audioBuffer;
}
let startAt = 0
const streamDestination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
/**
 * Note this is a minimum example it plays only the first sound 
 * it uses the main audio context if it would use a
 * streamDestination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
 * 
 * @param {ArrayBufferLike|Float32Array} data 
 */
const play = (data) => {
    const audioBufferSourceNoce = audioContext.createBufferSource();  
    audioBufferSourceNoce.buffer = convertFloatToAudioBuffer(data);

    const context = audioContext; // streamDestination; // creates a MediaStream on streamDestination.stream property
    audioBufferSourceNoce.connect(context);    

    // here you will need a hugh enqueue algo that is out of scope for this answer
    startAt = Math.max(context.currentTime, startAt);
    source.start(startAt);
    startAt += buffer.duration;
    audioBufferSourceNoce.start(startAt);
}

// Here is your raw arrayBuffer ev.data
recorder.port.onmessage = (ev) => play(ev.data);

// connect the processor with the source
audioMediaElement.connect(recorder);
```

### Note

This is only the bare minimum to console.log the data that comes from the recorder processor and we take only 1 channel when you really want to process that data you should consider doing that in a worker again register a handler that post the data directly to that worker as else your mainprocess could get unresponsive if you do a lot of processing.

Comment:  nice, didn't really have time to look into that!

Comment: idk why, but destructuring does not work in testprocessor.js;  must do this instead : this.port.postMessage(inputChannel);// float32Array sent as byte[512]

Comment: @patrick i also do not know why it does not work for you but it is as sayed even only the bare minimum copyed from a much bigger project from me maybe my build pipe line did fix it. I only posted that because i saw the wrong answers.

Comment: Also you need this at the end of test-processor.js : registerProcessor("testprocessorr", RecorderWorkletProcessor); or it will not be available to your main code.

Answer (score 9):

Seems as if it's not possible to extract the audiobuffer from an MediaElementSourceNode.

see https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chromium-html5/HkX1sP8ONKs

Any reply proving me wrong is very welcome!

Comment: Today it is: see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70753627/2950649

Answer (score 6):

This is possible. See my post at http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/HTML5-audio-and-the-Web-Audio-API-are-BFFs. There is also a code snippet and example there. There are a few outstanding bugs, but loading an `<audio>` into the Web Audio API should work as you want.

```
// Create an <audio> element dynamically.
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'myfile.mp3';
audio.controls = true;
audio.autoplay = true;
document.body.appendChild(audio);

var context = new webkitAudioContext();
var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

// Wait for window.onload to fire. See crbug.com/112368
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  // Our <audio> element will be the audio source.
  var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  source.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(context.destination);

  // ...call requestAnimationFrame() and render the analyser's output to canvas.
}, false);
```

Comment: yep, but i'd love to know if it's possible to get the **buffer** from a MediaElementSource to use it as/in a bufferSourceNode (which has noteOn, noteOff, noteGrain etc. )?

Comment: why let +100 go to waste ... so there you go :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you found a better solution yet and I also checked the W3C link you posted:
http://www.w3.org/2011/audio/wiki/Spec_Differences#Reading_Data_from_a_Media_Element

But in order for it to really work you have to use [`AudioContext.createScriptProcessor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createScriptProcessor). I didn't yet tried this but basically you connect the source node (an audio element) to a script processor but then don't even output the audio if you don't need it. In the `onaudioprocess` callback you have direct access to the audio buffer data (in chunks of a specified size of course). There are examples in the link above.

Also I think you can somehow tweak the speed of the playback so that you can get more buffer arrays faster.